# Using LESS with the CSS "starts with" attribute selector

Tags: css, less

I have the following LESS:

```
.fas {
    &[class^="fa-users"] {
        position: relative;
        right: -4px;
    }
}
```

which compiles into this CSS:

```
.fas[class^="fa-users"] {
  position: relative;
  right: -4px;
}
```

What I want is all elements with a class of `.fas` AND a class that starts with `.fa-users` to apply these styles. Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: Show us your HTML as well. (I would bet the issue is simply that you don’t have any element in there, that actually qualifies for the conditions you formulated with your selector. “Starts with” is meant literally - `fa-users...` would have to be the _first_ class listed in the `class` attribute of the element.)

Comment: @misorude Ah, gotcha. Had no idea the "starts with" class had to actually be the first class, as I have `.fas` as the first class in all of my elements. Thank you for the help!